# cardinality of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove if $ |A| < |B| $ and $ |B| \leq |C|$

then $ |A| < |C|$

I know that $|A| < |B|$ means there is a one to one mapping of A onto a SUBSET of B but no one to one mapping from A to B.

I also know that $|B| \leq |C|$ means there is a one to one mapping of B onto C.

I am going to try to prove this, but I am fairly confident its going to be full of holes, please help!

since $|A| < |B|$ there is $Z \subseteq B$ such that $f(a)=z$ for all $a \in A$ and $z\in Z$

since $|B| \leq |C|$ we have $f(b)=c$ for all $b \in B$ and $c\in C$

since $Z \subseteq B$ we have $f(z)=y$ for all $z \in Z$ and $y \in Y$ where $Y$ is a subset of $C$

since $f$ is one to one, then the inverse exists.

therefore $z = f^{-1}(y)$ for $z \in Z$ and $y \in Y$

therefore $f(a) = f^{-1}(y)$

okay now i'm lost.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's clarify something:

The notation $|A|<|B|$ means that:

1. There is a 1-1 function from $A$ into $B$.
2. There is no bijection from $A$ onto $B$.

Whereas the notation $|A|\leq|B|$ means only the first one. It may be that the second condition holds, or that it fails. For example $|\{0\}|\leq|\{0,1\}|$, and also $|\{1,2\}|\leq|\{0,1\}|$.

To show now that $|A|<|C|$ use the fact that there are two injections, $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ to come up with an injection $h\colon A\to C$. Next show that if there was a bijection from $A$ onto $C$ then there had to be one onto $B$ as well, which is absurd.

Comment: @Cameron: And I'm writing on an annoying tablet keyboard dock, from a bus with unstable wi-fi. What's your excuse? :-)

Comment: How do you get the final bijection onto $B$? Don't you need to use the fact that there is a surjection $C\to B$, and that if there is a bijection $A\to C$ you would get a surjection $A\to B$ which is absurd?

Comment: @dkuper: Unless one assumes the axiom of choice, surjections has no business in being involved here. It is consistent to have a surjection from a set onto a strictly larger set, when the axiom of choice fails. Secondly, you use the fact that if there was a bijection from $A$ onto $C$ then there was an injection from $B$ into $A$, and the Cantor-Bernstein theorem tells us that there is a bijection.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! I didn't think we would need a nontrivial result like  the Cantor-Bernstein to prove this transitivity result. And I didn't know this about axiom of choice and surjections :)

Comment: @dkuper: People often don't know these results regarding the axiom of choice. It's fine, because the axiom of choice is commonly assumed nowadays. However you can still find introductory courses/books where one does not assume it for basic cardinal arithmetic results like this one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  $|A|<|B|$ means there is an injection from $A$ onto a subset of $B$, but NO injection from $A$ onto $B$.  So I would need to consider a subset $Z$ of $B$ and say there exists an injection $f: A \rightarrow Z$ and an injection $g: B \rightarrow C$.  Therefore there exists an injection $h: Z \rightarrow C$ and so there exists an injection $h \circ f: A \rightarrow C$ and therefore $|A|<|C|$ does this make sense?

Comment: @Sarah: Yes, the definition of $<$ is the same as I wrote. Every function is onto its range (a subset of $B$), and a bijection is a function onto the codomain, so saying there is no bijection onto $B$ is to say that there is a bijection from $A$ onto $B$. The argument you gave it correct, but one doesn't have to pass through $Z$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I thought I'd have to stipulate the function is an injection onto a subset, and so introduced the subset $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach.  The conceptually simplest definition of $|\cdot|<|\cdot|$ I know is $$|A|<|B| \;\equiv\; |A|\le|B| \land |B|\not\le|A|$$  Using this definition we can rewrite our demonstrandum as follows:
\begin{align}
& |A|<|B| \land |B|\le|C| \;\Rightarrow\; |A|<|C| \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $|\cdot|<|\cdot|$, twice"} \\
& |A|\le|B| \land |B|\not\le|A| \land |B|\le|C| \;\Rightarrow\; |A|\le|C| \land |C|\not\le|A| \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"split RHS of $\Rightarrow$"} \\
& (|A|\le|B| \land |B|\not\le|A| \land |B|\le|C| \;\Rightarrow\; |A|\le|C| ) \;\land \\
& (|A|\le|B| \land |B|\not\le|A| \land |B|\le|C| \;\Rightarrow\; |C|\not\le|A|) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"simplify second part using contraposition"} \\
& (|A|\le|B| \land |B|\not\le|A| \land |B|\le|C| \;\Rightarrow\; |A|\le|C| ) \;\land \\
& (|A|\le|B| \land |C|\le|A| \land |B|\le|C| \;\Rightarrow\; |B|\le|A|) \\
\Leftarrow & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"strengthen by weakening LHS of $\Rightarrow$, twice"} \\
& \;\;\;\;\;\phantom{\text{"}}\text{-- because the shape of these formulas suggest transitivity"} \\
& (|A|\le|B| \land |B|\le|C| \;\Rightarrow\; |A|\le|C| ) \;\land \\
& (|B|\le|C| \land |C|\le|A| \;\Rightarrow\; |B|\le|A|) \\
\end{align}

Therefore all that is left to do is to prove that $|\cdot|\le|\cdot|$ is transitive, which should be easy enough.